# How to fix code to save all worksheets as one PDF? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, worksheet-function, worksheet

'How to fix code to save all worksheets as one PDF from the open workbook? VBA. It only prints the active worksheet right now for some reason.

Sub abc()

```
For i = 1 To Workbook.Worksheets.Count
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHeader = "Sample Excel File Saved As PDF"
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PrintArea = "$B$5:$F$105"
    .PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows(5).Address
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
 
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="Sample Excel File Saved As PDF 2", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=5, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
ActiveSheet.Next.Activate
Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

I did this very same thing just a few days ago. Try it like this.

```
Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Consolidated.pdf", Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Or, if you want specific ranges, do it like this.

```
one = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10")
two = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B10")
three = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:B10")

    Worksheets(Array(one, two, three)).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Consolidated.pdf", Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
         IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

one = ""
two = ""
three = ""
```